# what is the meaning of this injected sql?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I'm fiddling with `sqlmap` and it gives a working injected (My)SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `news`
WHERE (content LIKE ?)
ORDER BY id AND (
    SELECT 8183
    FROM (
        SELECT (sleep(1))
    ) dyYQ
)
```

But I fail to understand what this query means, mainly the `ORDER BY id AND (SELECT` part.

I understand both parts before and after `AND`, but I never knew `AND` could join two clauses.

I checked [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), `ORDER BY` followed by `AND subquery` does not look legal syntax.

Comment: If you see there in the syntax (`[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}`)  The expr?  That stands for any expression -- so it is legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is valid in MySQL, syntax wise. You can use any expression as the operands of the `and` operator. The result will be 1 or 0.

```
SELECT 1 AND (SELECT 1) -- 1
SELECT 1 AND (SELECT 0) -- 0
```

Plus the `... and ...` expression itself could be used in `order by`.

Comment: but your code is a bit different, how could `order by` be followed by `x AND y` , and what does it mean.
I know this is OK: `select * from table order by x desc, y asc` ， the sorted columns are joined by comma.

Comment: `x and y` is an expression which could be used just about anywhere. The `and` operator will return 0 or 1 and this is the value on which ordering is done.

Comment: You should note that if a number is used in an order by after the expression is evaluated it will order by the column number (in this case column 0 or column 1)

Comment: @hogan no. The column number has to be typed literally for that work... `order by 1` will order by first column, `order by (select 1)` will order by the "constant" 1.

Comment: @SalmanA -- very interesting point -- but the select is outside of the AND -- it was my understanding is the result of an expression will give the column -- thus you could calculate which column to sort on with `1 + 5` or `0 + SELECT usersortcol FROM options`.  It worked when I did this trick years ago in SQL Server, but I never tried in mysql

Comment: @hogan no, column can be specified by name, alias or position... and position must be integer, not an expression e.g. `order by 3+1`. MySQL will accept it syntax wise but order by a constant value 4, so basically all rows are considered equal for sorting. All this applies to sql server too.